# Как правильно пишется «топинг» или «топпинг»?

Tags: орфография, заимствования

Подскажите правописание слова «топинг». Оно пишется с одной «п» или с двумя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока в словарях это слово не фиксируется, происходит своеобразная "борьба" за термин среди его пользователей в областях кулинарии и строительных покрытий - каждый пишет как считает правильным. Пока статистически побеждает вариант с удвоенной "п" (вероятно, благодаря варианту во временных статьях википедии и гуглу), но не исключено, что со временем произойдёт упорядочивание, как это было с "**шопингом**". https://www.ekburg.ru/news/18/48054-kak-pravilno-shoping-ili-shopping/ Здесь вариант с одним "п" стал в словарях основным, поскольку английские удвоенные согласные (в shopping), используемые для организации закрытого слога, никогда не читаются с удвоением, в отличие от русского (где такое чтение почти обязательно, но бывает неудобным) или напр. итальянского языка (pizza/пицца), прямолинейная же транслитерация двойных согласных имеет ценность только в именах собственных, и то с ограничениями (напр. при нескольких удвоениях в одном слове, Mississippi -> Миссисипи). Поэтому можно ожидать, что к моменту появления в словарях написание будет скорректировано в соответствии с общей логикой, т. е. в направлении "**топинг**".